# Hypervisor Host Information for SQL Servers (non-Cloud) Virtual Servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to find the backend storage information through tsql? I've been asked to find out which servers are in what host in our environment.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: No

Longer Answer: Not natively, you'd have to ask for permission to the hypervisor's API, write a CLR stored procedure that would then authenticate and run said API to get whatever information you want, which even then it may not give you the exact details you'd like.